# Структура и архитектура набора компонентов UI

Tags: javascript, архитектура, компоненты

В очередной раз приходится участвовать в строительстве набора UI компонентов компании и в очередной раз сталкиваюсь с дилеммой.

Например, у нас есть некий Some UI, состоящий из стандартного набора компонентов, включающего `TextField`, `Checkbox`, `Radio` и прочие. Все бы хорошо, но в большинстве случаев для сложных интерфейсов фундаментальных возможностей этих компонентов становится недостаточно и приходится их расширять.

Возьмем компонент `TextField(input)`. Один из самых важных и часто используемых компонентов форм, позволяющих пользователю вводить текстовую информацию. С ним все хорошо, но со временем или сразу возникнет необходимость ограничивать тип вводимых в него данных, добавить иконку внутрь поля, показывать `callout` по клику на него и прочее. И вот тут и встает вопрос о стратегии расширения возможностей этого компонента.

Вот, например, есть задача: дать возможность пользователю ввести номер телефона в формате +(7) 123-45-67. Тут все предсказуемо, скорее всего вы бы добавите нашему `TextField` дополнительное свойство **phone**, принимающее **boolean**-значение, либо, если вы чуть более дальновидны, свойство **type**, принимающее значение **"phone"**. Все просто.

Появляется следующая задача: добавить возможность вводить в поле сумму в рублях в формате **00,00**, и запилить иконку валюты внутрь поля. Эта задача в реализации немного сложнее предыдущей и здесь возникает соблазн сделать её в виде отдельного компонента, например, `MoneyField`. Кажется, в этом есть смысл, так как это облегчит код основного компонента. В подобных ситуациях нужно принимать решение о стратегии расширения этого компонента, либо создавать отдельный компонент, либо расширять нынешний, например, через тоже свойство **type**.

Я сильно склоняюсь к варианту "прокачки" единственного компонента. Пусть лучше это будет монстр `TextField` с большим количеством параметров, чем множество мелких и легких компонентов, решающих точечные задачи. Знаю, что второй вариант многим, на первый взгляд, кажется более привлекательным, но поработав с таким решением пару лет, понимаю, что это не самая лучшая стратегия. С другой стороны я не уверен что вариант с прокачкой единственного компонента покажет себя лучше со временем, хотя в теории у меня все сходится :)

Короче, если бы вы создавали набор компонентов UI (вроде `Material UI`, `Fabric`, `Kendo` и пр.) какой подход в расширении базовых компонентов вы бы использовали? Круто, если у кого-то есть реальный опыт создания больших базовых компонентов. Поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: [какой подход в расширении базовых компонентов вы бы использовали?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Говоря про компонентный подход, нельзя не упомянуть всеми известный `React`, который как раз продвигает философию компонентов, используя при этом функциональный подход. Можно конечно рассуждать на эту тему, хорошо ли подходит парадигма функционального программирования для написания `UI-компонентов`, но как по мне это идеальное решение. `UI` пишется за счет функциональных компонентов, а модель реализуется уже с помощью привычного нам `ООП`

Заданный вами вопрос в контексте функциональных компонентов решается за счет композиции компонентов, есть какие-то атомарные компоненты, типа `Input`, `Button` + есть составные, более сложные компоненты - комбинация атомарных компонентов.

Для примера, у нас есть кнопка (буду использовать синтаксис React компонентов, но там не очень сложно разобраться)

```
class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        // html компонента, который мы будем получать на выходе
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {this.props.buttonText}
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Компонент рисует простую кнопку, которая принимает два параметра: текст и обработчик события `click`

Представим, что теперь нам нужна кнопка авторизации (любая другая кнопка), которая при этом используется в нескольких местах. Тут как раз встает ваш вопрос, каким именно образом реализовать компонент, как дочерний класс компонента `Button`, либо как отдельный компонент, `React` предлагает решение, которое близко ко второму варианту, а именно компоненты высшего порядка, либо композиция компонентов

```
class AuthButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                buttonText='Авторизоваться'
                onClick={this.handleAuth}
            />
        )
    }
    handleAuth() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Мы создали новый компонент `AuthButton`, который использует компонент `Button`, передавая ему определенные параметры. Мы можем создать миллион таких вот кнопок, каждая из которых будет выполнять свою роль/роли, например мы можем как-то кастомизировать стили кнопки, не затрагивая саму кнопку, просто передавая параметры, мы можем создать `PrimaryButton`, `ErrorButton` и так далее.

Преимущество в том, что мы ни как не меняем компонент `Button`, соответственно нам не стоит заботиться, что где-то в другом месте из-за изменений `Button` может что-то сломаться + миллион параметров у одного компонента приводит к тяжелым последствиям в дальнейшей поддержке

Воспринимать компоненты в данном контексте можно, как простые функции. Поддерживать и тестировать маленькие функции (пусть их даже и много) легче, чем одну огромную.

Ничто не мешает вам разбить все на две папки, `UI`, где вот такие, почти что нативные компоненты + `Составные компоненты`, которые используют в себе стандартный `UI`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, ТС всё это прекрасно знает, но по какой-то неизвестной причине не хочет такой подход использовать. А вопрос сюда он задал, что бы оправдать свои желания делать несколько компонентов в рамках одного.

Comment: @Vasya Shmarovoz, автор очень коварен и замыслил нечто крайне темное))) Причина по которой не хочу описал. Потому что нет желания множить компоненты и использовать гибридный подход при котором phone - настраивается атрибутом компонента, а money - это уже отдельный компонент. Собственно вопрос и был обращен в том числе к тем, кто пробовал по другому. Я не говорил, что подход, который вы предлагете плох, он вполне обычен.

Comment: @ThisMan, спасибо, использовал такое, но вот хочется пойти по другому пути

Comment: @Harvey, а зачем идти по другому пути? Почему нельзя вынести `MoneyInput` и `PhoneInput` как отдельные компоненты и не заморачиваться. Подход который я описал как раз такое и предполагает

Comment: @ThisMan, потому как это многократно умножает количество компонентов в наборе, осложняет манипуляции с ними, а самое главное сложно определить правило, когда пилить новый компонент, а когда просто свойство.
Но да, миилион параметров у компонента это плохо, особенно если они взаимоисключающие или неработающие вместе, это веский аргумент, конечно

Comment: @Harvey, в каком наборе? Атомарный компонент у вас один - `Button`, все остальное это уже компоненты высшего порядка/контейнеры/что-то еще. И почему сложно управлять? Я вижу имя компонента и сразу понимаю, что он делает, абстрактный `Button` мне в этом не поможет, еще и с кучей параметров, которые все надо запомнить

Comment: @Harvey ответ оказался прост — вы, скорее всего, усложняли себе архитектуру, складывая всё в один мешок и путая компоненты низкой абстракции и компоненты контейнерного типа. Соответственно, плавать в них вам было сложно. Вам нужно разделить код компонентов на components и containers. В components будут находится компоненты, которые используются исключительно как составные части контейнеров или других компонентов, со входными параметрами. В containers будут контейнеры с иерархией, в которых находятся компоненты. Жить будет проще

Comment: @Harvey трудно поверить, что вы за два года не пришли сами к такому разделению

Comment: @Vasya Shmarovoz, странно, что вы все продолжаете попытки меня всячески задеть (уверяю, минус поставил не я :) ). Зачем?

Comment: @ThisMan, согласен таки )

Comment: В общем моя теория привести все к большим компонентам разбивается о пересечение свойств. Не может компонент иметь свойство зависимое от значения другого свойства, а иначе расширять компонент не выйдет

Answer (score 0):

В своих проектах решаю проблему через наследование. Есть базовый полу-абстрактный класс `TextFieldAbstract` содержащий основные методы и поля. Есть несколько отнаследованных классов в которых содержится реализация для всех специфических частей (`TextFieldText`, `TextFieldMoney`, `TextFieldNumber`, etc.). Это разумный баланс между дублированием кода и классом-монстром.

P.S. А `TextFieldAbstract` сам наследуется от `ControlAbstract`, в котором общие вещи для всех контролов (типа положения, Enabled/Disabled и т.п.). `ControlAbstract`, в свою очередь, наследован от базового `Object`.

Не знаю насколько это применимо в JS. Делайте поправку на то что описанный подход хорошо работает в C / Delphi / т.п.

Comment: Это тоже вариация на тему множества мелких компонентов. Работал с такой архитектурой тоже, когда базовый компонент экстендят другие. При чем создававший ту архитектуру тим лид так увлекся, что на каждую плевую функцию он экстендил и экстендил, все дальше и глубже, что в итоге вылилось в пресловутое переписывание заново.

Comment: @Harvey поэтому так важно искусство баланса между крайностями ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Вы бросаетесь от крайности в крайность. Между множеством мелких и часто ненужных компонентов и одним компонентом, заточенным под миллион задач есть середина. Если компонент представляет собой низкую абстракцию, то его ни в коем случае не нужно раздувать. Компонент должен решать одну задачу и в нём не должно быть много абстракций.

Если есть `Input` и нужно его расширить под ввод телефона, не стоит его кастомизировать и вводить ему поля. Лучше создать компонент `PhoneInput`, который будет являться контейнером для компонента `Input`, но с надстройками. Это и есть компонентный подход, это и переписывается легче, и тестируется проще, и дебажится лучше, и рефакторить это потом не придётся с клоунами на вертолётах.

Comment: Знаю, что крайность, но в этом случае, как раз она мне и нужна, как раз эта крайность даст мгновенное представление о том, как устроен наш набор компонентов. Если у нас есть "прокаченный" инпут, то вновь пришедшему разработчику достаточно знать, что он имеет все необходимые возможности, не хочу пилить набор UI с кривой логикой,  где phone реализован внутри компонента через свойсво, а денежный тип реализован уже через другой компонент, это искажение логики, которая в итоге приводит к хаусу в развитии свое UI, проходил такое :) Хочу чтобы логика была тупой и прозрачной.

Comment: Понимаю, что мое стремление в пользу универсальных монстром (хотя не таких уж и монстром по моим подсчетам ) )кажутся странными, ведь мы привыкли, что вещь, решающая точечную задачу, решит ее качественно, а универсальная решит всё, но хуже. Но вот мне кажется, что не в этом случае. Я уже начинал пилить набор UI в таком стиле, но успел около 30%  и он не прошел проверку временем, по этому и прошу товарищей, рассказать как оно будет

Comment: @Harvey Проблемы будут решены в том и в другом случае. Тут вопрос про удобство разработки. Вновь пришедший разработчик как раз таки будет рвать волосы, пытаясь понять связь между частями компонента и параметрами, который его изменяют. Я поддерживаю не первый проект вышеизложенным образом. И многие хорошие масштабируемые проекты, на которые я натыкаюсь в сети, работают сделаны именно так

Comment: @Harvey На счет «привыкли» говорить тоже бессмысленно, потому что дело не в привычке, а в том, что когда один компонент решает одну задачу это и есть реализация компонентного подхода, который вы пытаетесь сейчас обсуждать. 

Не знаю, пытались ли вы писать юнит-тесты под здоровые модули, у которых на выходе может быть черт пойми что, в зависимости от входных параметров. Но складывается ощущение, что нет